# trouble in short date when field type is varchar

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i have date field in database but unfortunately date field type is varchar. Date inserts like 08-07-2010(dd-mm-yy). i want to short data by date asc order (year) like 08-07-2009, 07-07-2010. when i am using "order by date asc" is short data by year like 07-07-2010, 08-07-2009 . Please give me any suggestion if you have my query is

```
select * from tbl_name order by date asc
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats the issue , nerver store date in varchar, you should store dates in mysql native date data types.
However in your case you need to convert the varchar date to real date using the function
`str_to_date`

```
mysql> select str_to_date('08-07-2010','%d-%m-%Y');
+--------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('08-07-2010','%d-%m-%Y') |
+--------------------------------------+
| 2010-07-08                           |
+--------------------------------------+
```

So the query should be

```
select * from tbl_name order by str_to_date(date,'%d-%m-%Y') asc
```